# How to interpret a mix of negative and positive coefficients in an autoregressive setting?

Tags: regression, autoregressive

Let's say I have an $AR(2)$ process with positive first coefficient and negative second coefficient, e.g: $$y_t = 0.5 y_{t-1} - 0.5 y_{t-2} + \varepsilon_t$$

1. First, is there a real-life or logical example for such a process? I mean, can you find a setting where this relationship is the actual DGP (even if it's just made up but makes sense)?
2. Second, how do I interpret this if these were my estimated
   coefficients? I know that the first lag has a positive influence on
   $y$ and the second lag a negative influence. But is there more to it or is this more of a sign for a badly specified model, e.g: using two highly correlated variables as regressors (e.g: height and shoe size)?
3. Lastly, what is wrong with the following intuition: Intuitively, I would expect this relation not to be possible in real life because it sort of violates a transitivity property: since today influences tomorrow in a positive way, and yesterday influenced today in a positive way, yesterday should also influence tomorrow in a positive way. You could interpret the negative second lag as a sort of mean-reverting behavior, i.e. to not let the process explode. But mean-reversion is given in any stationary AR(p) process. If you need fast mean-reversion, have a small coefficient - you don't need a large positive and a large negative one.

(I got this problem in an actual real-life regression where I regressed the electricity price on its lags + other variables.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1, one could, at a suitable frequency, think of biological predator-prey phenomena. When there are many, say, mice, there still tend to be many in the next period, but then, birds of prey also find a lot of food, so that many young birds survive, so that, with a delay, many mice get eaten. Then, there are few mice again, so that fewer birds survive, and the circle repeats.

If you find that answer compelling, then it is maybe also an answer to 2, in that it need not point to misspecification (although it surely may!). In any case, a common device to interpret such coefficients is to look at the impulse response function, so the coefficients of the $MA(\infty)$ representation of the process. Consider

```
plot(0:14, itsmr::ma.inf(list(phi=c(0.5,-0.5)))[1:15], type="l", lwd=2, col="salmon")
abline(h=0, lty=2)
```

[image]

This function summarizes how a shock to the variable propagates over time and is often easier to interpret than many coefficients at the same time.

As to 3, I would argue that it is worth distinguishing between the concepts of correlation and partial correlation - much like in general multiple linear regressions, where a regression coefficient measures the influence of some regressors *after having controlled for the others* and is different from the raw correlation of that regressor with the dependent variable.

In this case, it is known that the $p$th partial correlation of an AR(p) process is just the $p$th lag coefficient, so $-0.5$ in your case, while the second autocorrelation of an AR(2) process is
$$
\rho_2=\frac{\phi_1^2}{1-\phi_2}+\phi_2=-\frac{1}{3}
$$
You could have R verify that for you via

```
FinTS::plotArmaTrueacf(c(0.5,-0.5), lag.max=2, pacf=F, plot=F)$acf
FinTS::plotArmaTrueacf(c(0.5,-0.5), lag.max=2, pacf=T, plot=F)$pacf
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This doesn't answer the question. See comments (and upvote the other answer. )

Q1. I've come across a paper that had an effect almost like this (although now I can't find it, so I've remembered some detail wrong.*

Here's how I think you can get an effect.

Let's say you're looking at trainee doctors in medical school. Medical school is hard. Really, really hard.  Grades are determined by: how conscientious you are (almost how hard you work) and how smart you are.

In year 1, it's hard, but not super hard. So people who work harder get better grades. And smarter people get better grades.

In year 2, it's harder. Everyone is working as hard as they can. Conscientiousness is no longer a factor. Lazy people do as much work as non-lazy people.

In year 3, it's the same. So what are the coefficients? $y_{t-1}$ is positive, because how smart you are in year 2 is correlated with how smart you are in year 3.

But $y_{t-2}$ could be negative. Because the people who did well in year 1 are more conscientious - they got a boost, but that boost is artificial. Sure, if you ignored year 2, that would be positive. But if you condition on year 2 (which is how smart you are), you're looking at the effect of conscientiousness, which is essentially a kind of 'cheat'. Now, when we control for how smart you are, you get a decrement for being conscientious.

Q2. This is an example of a suppressor effect. I don't think it's a badly specified model.  Well, in one sense it is because we're missing a variable (smarts, in this case).

Q3. I think it is possible in real life. Another example;

Something very traumatic happens to a group of people. They are likely to experience post-traumatic stress disorder (PTSD). At t1 we assess their PTSD symptoms. The people who seem to have the most symptoms (or perhaps the most trauma) get treatment.

We assess their PTSD at time 2, the symptoms are positively correlated.

We assess again at time 3. Time three symptoms correlate with time 1 symptoms and time 2 symptoms.  But conditioning on time 2, time 1 has a negative effect, because the most symptomatic people had the largest drops.

Again, you're missing a variable - getting treatment.

Here's some R code that generates data that gives such an effect:

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 1000

F <- rnorm(n)

d <- data.frame(
  y1 = F + rnorm(n),
  y2 = F + rnorm(n),
  y3 = F + rnorm(n)
)

d$y3 <- d$y2 + d$y3
d$y2 <- d$y2 + d$y1

cor(d)

summary(lm(y3 ~ y2 + y1, data = d))
```

And the result:

```
A matrix: 3 × 3 of type dbl
y1  y2  y3
y1  1.0000000   0.8668383   0.5888675
y2  0.8668383   1.0000000   0.8403526
y3  0.5888675   0.8403526   1.0000000

Call:
lm(formula = y3 ~ y2 + y1, data = d)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.3738 -0.7690  0.0378  0.7820  3.6712 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.03268    0.03607  -0.906    0.365    
y2           1.31028    0.02911  45.012   <2e-16 ***
y1          -0.95839    0.05032 -19.045   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

*In my memory it was written by Eamonn Ferguson, was about grades in medical school, and was published in the British Medical Journal, maybe 15 years ago. Either my memory is bad or my google-fu is bad. In that paper the final outcome was grade, and the t1 and t2 measures were conscientiousness.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thoughts and examples! However, I don't see how they apply in the setting I described, since your examples are not a time series. 
First, you have 3 time points at which multiple observations (grades) occur. This corresponds to having 3 variables and regressing them on each other. But it's not a single time series process. You can interpret that as many time processes with only 3 observations. Second, the "easy" first year is an outlier. If we assume the process was to run indefinitely, i.e. inf medical school & all years after are hard, its effect will fade out.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. Yeah, this might not work then.